# Can't get the white space to go away when using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to ge rid of the white space as seen on the picture. I am using bootstrap for my project and I'm fairly new to it. My teacher told me (without looking at any line of code) that it probably is some container that is making this issue but I beg to differ, since the html container is the one NOT taking up the entire screen, it feels to me that theres something going on with that element but I have no css for the HTML element, therefore it must be something with bootstrap? Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is? [screenshot where the html is marked and you can see the white box on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjxy0.png)

```css
.page-break {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url("images/welcome-img.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;

  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4db53af2d4.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <section class="top-bar">
        <div class="row sticky-top">
          <img src="images/tux.png" alt="" class="col-2" />
          <h2 class="col-5">About Linux</h2>
          <div class="col-5 hamburger-menu">MENU</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="hero-image row">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>FOSS</h1>
          <p>And why it's good for you</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <section class="hero-section">
        <div class="hero-container">
          <img src="images/welcome-img.jpg" alt="" />
          <h1>FOSS</h1>
          <h3>And why it's good for you</h3>
        </div>
      </section>-->
      <section class="articles container">
        <article class="manjaro-article">
          <div class="container gx-4 mt-4">
            <div class="row">
              <img src="images/manjaro_scrn.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="row py-3">
              <img src="logos/manjaro.svg" alt="" class="col-3 pe-4" />
              <h2 class="col-9"><b>Manjaro</b></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <p>
                Is an accessible, friendly, open-source operating system.
                Providing all the benefits of cutting-edge software combined
                with a focus on getting started quickly, automated tools to
                require less manual intervention, and help readily available
                when needed. Manjaro is suitable for both newcomers and
                experienced computer users.
              </p>
              <br />
              <br />
              <p>
                Unlike proprietary operating systems you have full control over
                your hardware without restrictions. This makes Manjaro a
                powerful Operating System ideal in home, work, and development
                environments.
              </p>
              <br />
              <br />
              <p>
                It is easily possible to run many popular Windows applications,
                using compatibility software such as Wine, PlayonLinux or Proton
                via Steam. The examples given here are far from comprehensive!
              </p>
              <br />
              <br />
              <p>
                Representing a perfect middle-ground for those who want good
                performance, full control, and cutting-edge software but also a
                degree of software stability.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <div class="row page-break">
          <div>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p></p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a div with the class `container` to wrap everything.
Add `<div class="container">` before `<header>` and close it after `</footer>` with `</div>`.
Please read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/) to understand the Bootstrap layout.

Comment: Thank you and I will read it through thoroughly